# Handling timezones

Tags: sql-server

I have a view on a database that gets me the status of some work items. For example, it gets a start date, and end date, and then does some maths based on `GetDate()` to return me a '`Work Remaining`' type of answer.

Problem is, the database server is in the United States and I am sitting in Australia.

So, the time here now is 19h33 on the 20th of July, and `GetDate()` on the server returns 02h33 on the 20th.

How should timezones be handled? Should my userprofile have a timezone field, and I deduct or add hours on the client side? Problem with that is that everything needs to manipulate dates and times. That is, the application, and any reports.

I have a view, for example, that returns me the remaining hours of a particular piece of work. It uses GETDATE() to calculate this:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vwSprintSummary] AS
SELECT 
    SprintId, 
    SprintName, 
    MIN(DateValue) AS FirstSprintDate,
    MAX(DateValue) AS LastSprintDate,
    SprintEndDate,
    COUNT(DISTINCT PersonId) AS AssignedPeople, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT ProjectResourceId) AS AssignedRoles, 
    SUM(AssignedProductiveHours * CanBurnDown) AS Capacity,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) <= DateValue THEN AssignedProductiveHours* CanBurnDown ELSE 0 END) AS RemainingCapacity
FROM [vwSprintDailyBreakdown]
GROUP BY SprintName, SprintId, SprintStartDate, SprintEndDate
GO
```

Somehow, I need to change the GetDate() to a 'DATEADD...' so that I can get answers in the correct time zone?

In this case, a 'fix' would be to change the `GETDATE()` to `DATEADD(HOUR, 17, GETDATE())`

Hardcoded, I know, but in essence, that would fix a problem.

Is there no way to somehow tell the server my zone, and get it to return dates based on my location?

Comment: It partly depends on the nature of the date/time in question. For example, did the source data also have an associated time zone, or is it just "an instant in time"? What does the "end date" of a work item really mean - does *that* have an associated time zone? There are lots of things to think about here, and no one-size-fits-all answer.#

Comment: Thanks Jon. I've posted an example of my problem. Times are stored as the Datetime.Now from the application. And actually, the time portion is not used. I'm focused on days (Most dates stored as DATE).

Comment: Why are they stored as `DateTime.Now`? As Dai says, it's *usually* better to store things in UTC. I would personally send up the current date/time in the query too rather than using GETDATE in the SQL - if you can control everything from one place, it'll be simpler (I think!)

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, store all information in your database in UTC and do all business-logic processing in UTC too, only convert to a local timezone in your presentation-logic layer - this approach will save you no-end of trouble, and means that the database server can (and should) remain blissfully unaware of your timezone.

In my own projects I tend to trust the webserver's clock rather than the database server's clock, so I never use `GETUTCDATE()` on the SQL Server, instead I provide all dates and times to the as a SQL parameter, e.g. a query to find "orders placed today" will provide its own definition of "today" (i.e. by providing a minimum and maximum date/time value).

Comment: Thanks Dai. I've posted an example of my problem. The fact that I get items based on a GETDATE(). This is a view, but based on another view which does all the hard data mining. The other view doesn't use GETDATE(). It simply gets all the data together, which I then use other views and queries (From Entity Framework, in most cases) to display the data. The only problem I have right now, is that this view (in the example) uses GetDate(). Would I pass a 'TimeDelta' to the view, somewhow, to modify the GETDATE value?